# how to get dates between two dates('FromDate and ToDate') and if we have the null value In Todate we should change to getdate() In Todate?

Tags: sql-server

I have  a Table With PatientID and FromDate and Todate,I want to generate the dates between these two dates and one more main important scenario is,If we have Null in the Todate We have to Convert that Null Into Getdate() and then get the Dates and *"This query should be done without using 'CTE' AND 'While'."*

```
Declare @Temp AS TABLE
(
PatientID INT,
FromDate DATE,
ToDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(3,'2014-05-16','2014-05-16')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(3,'2014-05-16','2014-05-22')
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(3,'2014-05-22',NULL)
SELECT * FROM @Temp
```

[image]

Comment: Create and use a calendar table then if you have the (unrealistic) requirement of not using a CTE.

Comment: @ larnu   Cant we do without using cte because i have to put it in the stored procedure

Comment: You can use CTE's in a stored procedure.  Although you don't need one here.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft  Could you please do the Query, So it can be  be helpful for me.

Comment: As David said you can most certainly use a CTE in a procedure, though a Calendar table isn't a CTE, it's (as the name suggests) a `TABLE`.

Comment: @Larnu can  you  do  the query  and show how it works

Comment: Have a Google (or use your preferred search engine) of "Calendar Table SQL Server"; you'll find a huge wealth of resources.

Comment: @Larnu can you please do using Cte?

Comment: I can, yes. I recommend a Tally, especially if you are going to have large date ranges; otherwise you can use an rCTE.

Comment: @Larnu  I dont have large Date ranges,you can do with 'RCte'

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service. As a self-professed SQL Developer at an enormous multi-national consulting / outsourcing company, you should have resources to help you write (learn?) tsql. And it seems asking someone to write a query using a rCTE contradicts your directive (last line) to not use a CTE.

Comment: @SMor I tried the code but the code is completly irrelevant so thats why i asked my question.i know so is not a free code writing service.i am not asking stack overflow  to complete my project by writing whole code.i am just asking to solve only this problem.